# Are inverse matrices unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does a matrix have only one inverse matrix (like the inverse of an element in a field)? If so, does this mean that

$A,B \text{ have the same inverse matrix} \iff A=B$?

Comment: You may check this before you read further, to prove it yourself. Hint : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix

Answer (score 28, accepted):

More generally, in any situation where the associative law holds, if some $x$ has both a left-inverse $l$ and a right inverse $r$, then $l=r$.  The reason is that $l=l(xr)=(lx)r=r$. In particular, if $x$ has a $2$-sided inverse, then that's unique.  On the other hand, it is entirely possible for some $x$ to have many different left-inverses if it has no right-inverse.  It is also possible for some $x$ to have many right-inverses if it has no left-inverse. Both of these possibilities actually happen in the case of non-square matrices.

Comment: (+1) It can also happen if instead of matrices we consider linear transformations $V\to V$. If $V$ is infinite-dimensional, then there are transformations with many left-inverses and no right-inverse, or vice versa.

Answer (score 9):

Specific counterexample to the non-square case: Let $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Then there is a matrix $B$ such that $AB=I$, namely $B=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\x&y\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.  Note that $x,y$ can each be anything, so this right inverse is not unique.  Also note that $I$ is $2\times 2$.

On the other hand, there is *no* matrix $C$ such that $CA=I$, where now $I$ would have to be $3\times 3$.  The reason is that the last column of $A$ is all zeroes, so the last column of $CA$ would be all zeroes as well.  Thus $A$ has no left inverse at all.

Answer (score 7):

If $A$, $B$ are square matrices with same inverse $C$, then $AC=CA=I$ and $BC=CB=I$. Therefore,
$$
        A =AI= A(CB)= (AC)B = IB = B.
$$
The odd thing about matrices is this: If $A$, $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices over a field, then $AB=I$ iff $BA=I$. This is a direct consequence of the fact that the $N\times N$ matrices form a finite-dimensional linear space.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $GL(n, \mathbb{F})$, the set of invertible $n\times n$ matrices over the field $\mathbb{F}$, is a group. In any group, inverses are unique, so if $a^{-1} = b^{-1}$, by taking inverses it follows that $a = b$. In particular, this applies to the group $GL(n, \mathbb{F})$.

Comment: What GL stands for?

Comment: @gbox the set of all the invertible matrices

Comment: General linear. The group $GL(n, \mathbb{F})$ is often called the [general linear group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group).

Comment: But how do we know that $GL(n,\mathbb F)$ is a group in the first place? That's because we _already_ know matrix inverses behave like they ought to.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: In verifying that $GL(n, \mathbb{F})$ is a group, we do not need to prove that if $A^{-1} = B^{-1}$ then $A = B$. My point was that this implication is true in any group, in particular $GL(n, \mathbb{F})$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is unique. To show this, assume a matrix $A$ has two inverses $B$ and $C$, so that $AB=I$ and $AC=I$. Therefore $AB=AC \implies BAB=BAC \implies B=C$. So the inverse is indeed unique. For the second question, note that $(A^{-1})^{-1}=A$ so that if $A$ and $B$ both have inverse $A^{-1}$, then $A^{-1}$ has a unique inverse as well. Since $A$ and $B$ are both inverses, therefore $A=B$.

Comment: Your calculation depends on $B$ being a _two-sided_ inverse (or at least on $A$ having _some_ left inverse), which seems to deserve a proof of its own. (E.g., [here](http://www.mcs.sdsmt.edu/ecorwin/abstract_algebra/fall96/one_sidedU.htm))

Comment: (Ignore the link in the above comment. It assumes that every right inverse has a right inverse itself).

Comment: @Pauly B Does it hold if we assume that more than two inverses matrices exist?